# How to add new column based on row condition in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add new column based on row condition which is based on two different columns of same dataframe.

I have below **Dataframe** -

```
df1_data = {'e_id': {0:'101',1:'',2:'103',3:'',4:'105',5:'',6:''},
        'r_id': {0:'',1:'502',2:'',3:'504',4:'',5:'506',6:''}}
df=pd.DataFrame(df1_data)
print df
```

I want to add new column named as "sym".

**Condition -**

1. If 'e_id' column value is not null then sym column value is 'e_id' column value.
2. If 'r_id' column value is not null then sym column value is 'r_id' column value.
3. If 'e_id' and 'r_id' both column values are null then remove this particular row from pandas dataframe.

I tried with below code -

```
df1_data = {'e_id': {0:'101',1:'',2:'103',3:'',4:'105',5:''},
        'r_id': {0:'',1:'502',2:'',3:'504',4:'',5:'506'}}

df=pd.DataFrame(df1_data)
print df

if df['e_id'].any():
    df['sym'] = df['e_id']
print df

if df['r_id'].any():
    df['sym'] = df['r_id']
print df
```

But it is giving me a wrong output.

Expected output -

```
  e_id r_id  sym
0  101       101
1       502  502
2  103       103
3       504  504
4  105       105
5       506  506
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`pandas`***
*Using `mask` + `fillna` + `assign`*

```
d1 = df.mask(df == '')
df.assign(sym=d1.e_id.fillna(d1.r_id)).dropna(subset=['sym'])

  e_id r_id  sym
0  101       101
1       502  502
2  103       103
3       504  504
4  105       105
5       506  506
```

---

***How It Works***

- I need to mask your `''` values with the assumption that you meant those to be null
- By using `fillna` I take `e_id` if it's not null otherwise take `r_id` if it's not null
- `dropna` with `subset=['sym']` only drops the row if the new column is null and that is only null if both `e_id` and `r_id` were null

---

***`numpy`***
*Using `np.where` + `assign`*

```
e = df.e_id.values
r = df.r_id.values
df.assign(
    sym=np.where(
        e != '', e,
        np.where(r != '', r, np.nan)
    )
).dropna(subset=['sym'])

  e_id r_id  sym
0  101       101
1       502  502
2  103       103
3       504  504
4  105       105
5       506  506
```

***`numpy` v2***
*Reconstruct the dataframe from values*

```
v = df.values
m = (v != '').any(1)
v = v[m]
c1 = v[:, 0]
c2 = v[:, 1]
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([v, np.where(c1 != '', c1, c2)]),
    df.index[m], df.columns.tolist() + ['sym']
)

  e_id r_id  sym
0  101       101
1       502  502
2  103       103
3       504  504
4  105       105
5       506  506
```

---

***Timing***

```
%%timeit
e = df.e_id.values
r = df.r_id.values
df.assign(sym=np.where(e != '', e, np.where(r != '', r, np.nan))).dropna(subset=['sym'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df.mask(df == '')
df.assign(sym=d1.e_id.fillna(d1.r_id)).dropna(subset=['sym'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop

%%timeit
v = df.values
m = (v != '').any(1)
v = v[m]
c1 = v[:, 0]
c2 = v[:, 1]
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([v, np.where(c1 != '', c1, c2)]),
    df.index[m], df.columns.tolist() + ['sym']
)
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

First filter both empty columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df = df[(df != '').any(1)]
#alternatively
#df = df[(df['e_id'] != '') | (df['r_id'] != '')]
```

Then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['sym'] = df['e_id'].mask(df['e_id'] == '').combine_first(df['r_id'])
print (df)

  e_id r_id  sym
0  101       101
1       502  502
2  103       103
3       504  504
4  105       105
5       506  506
```

Numpy solution with filtering and [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = df[(df['e_id'] != '') | (df['r_id'] != '')]
e_id = df.e_id.values
r_id = df.r_id.values
df['sym'] = np.where(e_id != '', e_id, r_id)
print (df)
  e_id r_id  sym
0  101       101
1       502  502
2  103       103
3       504  504
4  105       105
5       506  506
```

Comment: @jezrael- I'm facing TypeError: Could not compare [''] with block values error in df = df[(df != '').any(1)] line but your alternate solution works fine. ;-)

Comment: Ok, no problem. Btw, alternative solution is faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with column 'e_id' and replace its values with 'r_id' values whenever 'e_id' is "empty", using `pandas.DataFrame.mask` and the `'other'` parameter:

```
df['sym'] = df['e_id'].mask(df['e_id'] == '', other=df['r_id'], axis=0)
```

then you just need to remove rows where `sym` is "empty"

```
df = df[df.sym!='']
```